# MailKit can't search James' old emails?

Tags: c#, mailkit, james

Development environment: C#, Core 3.1, MailKit 3.5.0, Apache James 3.3.0

Using the same code, after restarting the James service, the old emails will not be found.

```
using (var imapClient = new ImapClient())
{
    var sent = imapClient.GetFolder("Sent");
    sent.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly);
    var query = SearchQuery.DeliveredAfter(DateTime.Parse("2023-02-01")).And(SearchQuery.All);
    var uids = sent.Search(query);
}
```

The goal is to use SearchQuery in Imap mode to query the sendbox mailing list after a certain date

Answer (score 0):

Your search query should work unless the IMAP server is broken.

FWIW, I'm not sure why you are combining your date query with ALL:

```
var query = SearchQuery.DeliveredAfter(DateTime.Parse("2023-02-01")).And(SearchQuery.All);
```

You can just use this:

```
var query = SearchQuery.DeliveredAfter(DateTime.Parse("2023-02-01"))
```

Maybe simplifying your query will be less confusing to your server?

Comment: Hello, I have also tried this statement, and the flag is also None.It can also be traversed using Fetch

Comment: Then most likely your IMAP server is broken.